# Dealing with overflow in Java without using BigInteger

Tags: java

Suppose I have a method to calculate combinations of r items from n items:

```
    public static long combi(int n, int r) {

        if ( r == n) return 1;
        long numr = 1;
        for(int i=n; i > (n-r); i--) {
            numr *=i;

        }
        return numr/fact(r);

    }


public static long fact(int n) {

        long rs = 1;
        if(n <2) return 1;
        for (int i=2; i<=n; i++) {
            rs *=i;
        }
        return rs;

    }
```

As you can see it involves factorial which can easily overflow the result. For example if I have fact(200) for the foctorial method I get zero. The question is why do I get zero?

Secondly how do I deal with overflow in above context? The method should return largest possible number to fit in long if the result is too big instead of returning wrong answer.

One approach (but this could be wrong) is that if the result exceed some large number for example 1,400,000,000 then return remainder of result modulo 
1,400,000,001. Can you explain what this means and how can I do that in Java?

Note that I do not guarantee that above methods are accurate for calculating factorial and combinations. Extra bonus if you can find errors and correct them.

Note that I can only use int or long and if it is unavoidable, can also use double. Other data types are not allowed.

I am not sure who marked this question as homework. This is NOT homework. I wish it was homework and i was back to future, young student at university. But I am old with more than 10 years working as programmer. I just want to practice developing highly optimized solutions in Java. In our times at university, Internet did not even exist. Today's students are lucky that they can even post their homework on site like SO.

Comment: Use BigIntegers to prevent overflow.

Comment: Calculating the number of combinations without overflowing can be done better by adjusting your algorithm to never call `fact` and properly ordering operations.

Comment: It may be true that the result, if <= MAX_INT, will be correct anyway due to the properties of modular arithmetic, but that is a total stab in the dark.

Comment: @keith.layne It is possible that the result would be such that if it was built up by successive modular additions, it would have surpassed Long.MAX_VALUE and wrapped into negative territory, but kept going until it landed in positive territory again, ending up with a small positive value far from the (large) correct result.

Comment: @amc It seems most answerers missed your first question about `fact(200)` returing 0 because the second part was so interesting. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question (why did you get zero), the values of fact() as computed by modular arithmetic were such that you hit a result with all 64 bits zero!  Change your fact code to this:

```
public static long fact(int n) {
    long rs = 1;
    if( n <2) return 1;
    for (int i=2; i<=n; i++) {
        rs *=i;
        System.out.println(rs);
    }
    return rs;
}
```

Take a look at the outputs!  They are very interesting.

Now onto the second question....

It looks like you want to give exact integer (er, `long`) answers for values of `n` and `r` that fit, and throw an exception if they do not.  This is a fair exercise.

To do this properly you should not use factorial at all.  The trick is to recognize that `C(n,r)` can be computed incrementally by adding terms.  This can be done using recursion with memoization, or by the multiplicative formula mentioned by Stefan Kendall.

As you accumulate the results into a `long` variable that you will use for your answer, check the value after each addition to see if it goes negative.  When it does, throw an exception.  If it stays positive, you can safely return your accumulated result as your answer.

To see why this works consider Pascal's triangle

```
1
1  1
1  2   1
1  3   3   1
1  4   6   4   1
1  5  10  10   5  1
1  6  15  20  15  6  1
```

which is generated like so:

```
C(0,0) = 1 (base case)
C(1,0) = 1 (base case)
C(1,1) = 1 (base case) 
C(2,0) = 1 (base case) 
C(2,1) = C(1,0) + C(1,1) = 2
C(2,2) = 1 (base case)
C(3,0) = 1 (base case)
C(3,1) = C(2,0) + C(2,1) = 3
C(3,2) = C(2,1) + C(2,2) = 3
...
```

When computing the value of `C(n,r)` using memoization, store the results of recursive invocations as you encounter them in a suitable structure such as an array or hashmap. Each value is the sum of two *smaller* numbers.  The numbers start small and are always positive.  Whenever you compute a new value (let's call it a subterm) you are adding smaller positive numbers.  Recall from your computer organization class that whenever you add two modular positive numbers, there is an overflow *if and only if* the sum is negative.  It only takes one overflow in the whole process for you to know that the `C(n,r)` you are looking for is too large.

This line of argument could be turned into a nice inductive proof, but that might be for another assignment, and perhaps another StackExchange site.

**ADDENDUM**

Here is a complete application you can run.  (I haven't figured out how to get Java to run on codepad and ideone).

```
/**
 * A demo showing how to do combinations using recursion and memoization, while detecting
 * results that cannot fit in 64 bits.
 */
public class CombinationExample {

    /**
     * Returns the number of combinatios of r things out of n total.
     */
    public static long combi(int n, int r) {
        long[][] cache = new long[n + 1][n + 1];
        if (n < 0 || r > n) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Nonsense args");
        }
        return c(n, r, cache);
    }

    /**
     * Recursive helper for combi.
     */
    private static long c(int n, int r, long[][] cache) {
        if (r == 0 || r == n) {
            return cache[n][r] = 1;
        } else if (cache[n][r] != 0) {
            return cache[n][r];
        } else {
            cache[n][r] = c(n-1, r-1, cache) + c(n-1, r, cache);
            if (cache[n][r] < 0) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Woops too big");
            }
            return cache[n][r];
        }
    }

    /**
     * Prints out a few example invocations.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] data = ("0,0,3,1,4,4,5,2,10,0,10,10,10,4,9,7,70,8,295,100," +
                "34,88,-2,7,9,-1,90,0,90,1,90,2,90,3,90,8,90,24").split(",");
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i += 2) {
            int n = Integer.valueOf(data[i]);
            int r = Integer.valueOf(data[i + 1]);
            System.out.printf("C(%d,%d) = ", n, r);
            try {
                System.out.println(combi(n, r));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it is useful.  It's just a quick hack so you might want to clean it up a little....  Also note that a good solution would use proper unit testing, although this code does give nice output.

Comment: This sounds like very efficient solution but the recursive solution gives me stackoverflow error when I use large values. Can you sugguest with a few lines of code how your solution can be done non-recursively?

Comment: @amc You should not get a stack overflow if you properly **memoize**.  In case memoization is new to you, I've added a complete application to my answer that illustrates the technique.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [multiplicative formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Multiplicative_formula), instead of the factorial formula.

[image]

Comment: +1: I would be interested to know how you do this with integers and not end up with much the same problem.

Comment: If you reverse the denominator, you can do it in numerator/denominator pairs: `n / 1 * (n - 1) / 2 * (n - 2) / 3 * ...`

Comment: I tried this multiplicative formula but I did not get any better performane than the solution I posted. The difference is that we are trading multiplications (in my case) with divisions in your formula.

Answer (score 4):

Since its homework, I won't want to just give you a solution.  However a hint I will give is that instead of calculating two large numbers and dividing the result, try calculating both together. e.g. calculate the numerator until its about to over flow, then calculate the denominator.  In this last step you can chose the divide the numerator instead of multiplying the denominator. This stops both values from getting really large when the ratio of the two is relatively small.

I got this result before an overflow was detected.

```
combi(61,30) = 232714176627630544 which is 2.52% of Long.MAX_VALUE
```

The only "bug" I found in your code is not having any overflow detection, since you know its likely to be a problem. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `java.math.BigInteger` class to deal with arbitrarily large numbers.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that I cannot use BigInteger. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you make the return type `double`, it can handle up to `fact(170)`, but you'll lose some precision because of the nature of `double` (I don't know why you'd need exact precision for such huge numbers).

For input over `170`, the result is [infinity](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#POSITIVE_INFINITY)

Comment: +1 While the fact the OP tagged this "homework" leads me to believe some professor is looking to see how the students can use knowledge of modular arithmetic in this problem to both compute exact results and detect overflow (academics tend to like this stuff), the use of double in this case is a solid, practical answer.  It might not meet the OP's criterion of "unavoidable" but I agree that it probably doesn't have to.  You can go much farther than 2^63-1 with doubles and anyone aware of IEEE-754 basics should have no trouble with `Infinity`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that java.lang.Long includes constants for the min and max values for a long.

When you add together two signed 2s-complement positive values of a given size, and the result overflows, the result will be negative.  Bit-wise, it will be the same bits you would have gotten with a larger representation, only the high-order bit will be truncated away.

Multiplying is a bit more complicated, unfortunately, since you can overflow by more than one bit.

But you can multiply in parts.  Basically you break the to multipliers into low and high halves (or more than that, if you already have an "overflowed" value), perform the four possible multiplications between the four halves, then recombine the results.  (It's really just like doing decimal multiplication by hand, but each "digit" is, say, 32 bits.)

Answer (score -1):

You can copy the code from java.math.BigInteger to deal with arbitrarily large numbers.  Go ahead and plagiarize.